# Organizing .html.erb and .js.erb files within a view directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view directory called `blogs`.  Within that directory you can find all the standard, conventional html view templates:

```
# html files within the app/views/blogs directory 
  _form.html.erb
  edit.html.erb
  index.html.erb
  new.html.erb
  show.html.erb
```

However: I also have some ajax views that dynamically change content on pages (mostly just content on the form).  currently they are all all mixed in with the `.html.erb` files which feels kind of cluttered and unorganized:

```
# now showing the html AND js files within the app/views/blogs directory 
  _form.html.erb
  add_foobar.js.erb
  add_barbazz.js.erb
  edit.html.erb
  filter_by_team.js.erb
  filter_by_city.js.erb
  filter_by_state.js.erb
  index.html.erb
  new.html.erb
  show.html.erb
```

I think it would make sense to seperate the `.html.erb` files from the `js.erb` files, though I am not sure how to do this because they all belong within the `blogs` directory.

How can I organize the `.js.erb` and `.html.erb` files within this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say to your action where exactly template is

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render "blogs/js/filter_by_team" }
end
```

And place js template into `views/blogs/js`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you place the .js files in another directory and use content_for to inject them. like this -

http://www.railscook.com/recipes/how-to-organize-page-specific-javascript/